# How can I combine FromSqlRaw() and Where() in an Entity Framework query?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, full-text-search

I have the following query to get ranked full text search results:

```
OrgsSqlWhere = "SELECT top 200 * FROM FreeTextTable(Organizations, *, {0}, 200) as t INNER JOIN Organizations u on u.Id = t.[KEY] ORDER BY t.[RANK] desc";

 // ...

listOrgs = await dbContext.Organizations 
                          .FromSqlRaw(OrgsSqlWhere, Query)
                          .Include(o => o.Parent)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

However, I need to add the following `Where()` clauses:

```
public static IQueryable<Event> WhereWithinRange(this IQueryable<Event> source, Point? location, int distance)
{
    var meters = MiscUtils.MilesToMeters(distance);
    var query = source
        .Where(e =>
            e.Workplace != Event.WorkplaceType.InPerson
            || e.Address.Location == null
            || location == null
            || e.Address.Location.Distance(location) < meters);
    return query;
}

public static IQueryable<Event> WherePublic(this IQueryable<Event> source)
{
    var query = source.Where(e => (! e.Private) && (e.Enabled) && (! e.Deleted));
    return query;
}
```

It allows the following:

```
listOrgs = await dbContext.Organizations
            .FromSqlRaw(OrgsSqlWhere, Query)
            .WhereWithinRange(location, maxDistance)
            .WherePublic()
            .Include(o => o.Parent)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this is putting the `Where()` after the `order by`. I looked at the actual SQL generated (which is incredibly complex) and I think what it's doing is it has an inner select that is the `FromSqlRaw()` and the results of that are then processed in an outer select.

The inner select has the `ORDER BY t.[RANK] desc` but then the outer select has this very complex `order by` with a bunch of columns in it.

My questions are:

1. Is this an effective way to do this? Or do I need to put my where clauses into the query I pass to `FromRawSql()`?
2. Does it keep the `ORDER BY t.[RANK] DESC`? Or do I need to re-sort by `RANK` the returned results?

[Here's the generated SQL](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/5nv3k2ti7pcdqjxvpkho3/GeneratedSql.txt?rlkey=6edo8teunezqqzee4vz9lo2h2&dl=1) (attached because of its size).